# i want to configure teamcity build configuration to deploy Java War file to Octopus

Tags: java, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I want to add a build pipeline in teamcity to deploy a Java API using Octopus. i need help creating teamcity build steps like compile, create WAR, Replace config variables, Push WAR file to Octopus Repository using Maven.

Comment: `compile, create WAR, Replace config variables` depends on your build tool (ant, gradle, maven). and normally this info should be provided by developer

Comment: Its maven. I will use maven

Comment: https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploy-java-app/to-tomcat/using-octopus-onprem-teamcity-builtin steps you through the process of building and deploying a Java app with Octopus.